# How to prevent a DIV from expanding in width?

Tags: html, css, width

How do I prevent a `div` from expanding in width?

I'd like `.dont-expand` to pretend that `width: 100%;` means "100%, but not counting myself".  Basically, compute `width: 100%;` (ignoring itself), and setting that width in pixels `width: Npx;` -- in CSS and not JS.

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* This element sets the width of the container */
.has-width {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,128,0,.2);
  border-right: 2px solid green;
  color: #888;
}

.dont-expand {
  /* width: ??? */
  
  /* This would be nice       */
  /* expand: false;           */
  
  /* Or this                  */
  /* width: toPx(100%);       */
  
  /* Or this                  */
  /* width: calc(100% + 0px); */
}
```

```html
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="dont-expand">
      How do I get this text to wrap
      instead of growing the container?
    </div>
    <div class="has-width">
      I should be setting the width of "container".
    </div>
  </div>
```

[jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/zeqayelobi/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: One option might be to set `white-space: pre;` on your dont-expand class

Comment: @j08691 - I'm looking for something more general -- like "width: 100%;" but ignoring it's own width. I re-worded the question a little bit.

Comment: if it's about the screen width, you can use `vw` units : would `width:100vw` be what you looked for ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Sorry, not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you can make an element "appear" as 0 width to its parent, but still have it expand to the parent's width by doing: `width: 0px; min-width: 100%`.

This seems to be the cleanest, most browser-compatible solution. It also doesn't require changing the `display` property, which is a plus.

```css
 /* Make it "shrink-to-fit", either inline-block, or position: absolute */
 .outer {
    /* position: absolute; */
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  /* This element sets the width of the container */
  .has-width {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,128,0,.2);
    border-right: 2px solid green;
    color: #888;
  }

  /* Appears as 0 width to parent, but then expands to fit. */
  .dont-expand {
    width: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="dont-expand">
    How do I get this text to wrap
    instead of growing the container?
  </div>
  <div class="has-width">
    I should be setting the width of "container".
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, this is super useful! I wonder though if it's not a bit hacky way of achieving this, and we risk it being fixed (removed) in the future

Comment: I've been at a loss as to how this isn't able to be implemented in any cleaner way, other than tables, for about 15 years. I'm also confused as to how I'm one of a few people that seems to care about it or get confused that there is no clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: min-content;
}
```

This should make it so that the width of the outer box becomes as small as possible, while not squashing content.

Comment: +1 Your solution does work, but browser support for it isn't ubiquitous yet.  Also, in my use case I have limited ability to modify the parent. I really need something that modifies `dont-stretch` like: `width: 100%-in-pixels;`

Comment: @JS_Riddler width:100% of what ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Of its parent -- excluding its own width in the computation.

Comment: @JS_Riddler , okay, i only see the table-layout almost able to do this anytime, at this time and  able to shrink as much as possible but allowing to expand too to the width  of the smallest element

Answer (score 0):

You  may relay on the the `table-layout` property to shrink the container to the width of the smallest content.

You need then to set the width to `.has-content` to its actual content's width via `max-content`

`.dont-expand` requires no width, it will wrap inside the width avalaible, **unless itself has a word or an image wider than `.has-width`**, that is the only side behavior i know of.

example:

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  width: 0;
}


/* This element sets the width of the container */

.has-width {
  width: max-content;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, .2);
  border-right: 2px solid green;
  color: #888;
}

.dont-expand {
  /* nothing needed here */
}
.bis {bottom:0}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="dont-expand">
    How do I get this text to wrap instead of growing the container?
  </div>
  <div class="has-width">
    I should be setting the width of "container".
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer bis ">
  <div class="dont-expand">
    How do I get this text to wrap instead of growing the container?
  </div>
  <div class="has-width">
   i'm container's width ! 
  </div>
</div>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
>
> The table-layout CSS property sets the algorithm used to lay out  cells, rows, and columns.

here , there's nothing else than 1 column since, children of `.outer` do not have a `display` reset . The idea is to **only** use the shrink/expand native properties of the `table-layout display`  algorithm on the main wrapper and **not** rebuild a visual HTML table from div.

---

Play with this `table-layout` behavior to become familiar with it, and do not think about any `HTML` table tag, it's only about CSS styling ;)

[image: here is what to expect]

Comment: Looks promising -- but your snippet may be missing some style rules.

Comment: @JS_Riddler okay, which rules are missing ? (for infos : display:table comes from CSS2.1 since 1998, implemented in FF1 and Ie7 thus, implemented anywhere max-content or min-content is not ;) )  See that answer has an hint before to be your own answser )

Comment: The snippet you provided doesn't appear to shrink the container to the width of the `.has-width` element.

Comment: @JS_Riddler ?? okay, which browser are you using that it appears not working ? I added a screenshot of the snippet

Comment: I just now found a solution that requires minimal changes.  Setting `width: 0px` and `min-width: 100%` causes an element to "appear" as 0 width to its parent, but also causes it to expand to 100% width of its parent.

Comment: @js_riddler now i understand. min-width killed width value. ;) take care.

Answer (score -1):

Set the box-sizing property to "border-box"

```css
.dont-expand {
  /* width: ?? */

  /* This would be nice       */
  /* expand: false;           */

  /* Or this                  */
  /* width: toPx(100%);       */

  /* Or this                  */
  /* width: calc(100% + 0px); */


  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This appears to do nothing.

Comment: Did you set the width property as well?

Comment: The entire question is, in large part, "what should I set the width to". Do you have a suggestion?